# Downloading tweets using rtweet package appears to stop at 8%. Why?

Tags: r, rtweet

I am using the `rtweet` package to retrieve tweets on a specific hashtag.

My `R` codes stand as follows:

```
# load rtweet package
library(rtweet)

## search for 18000 tweets using the "singapore" hashtag
rt <- search_tweets(
  "#singapore", n = 18000, include_rts = FALSE
)
```

However, `RStudio` displays the following line when I execute the code:

```
Downloading [==>--------------------------------------]   8%
```

It then ends the execution with the above message still showing 8%.

`nrow(rt)` tells me 1,250

Note: When I executed the code, `rtweet` directed me to my web browser and I did the authentication via the web browser.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The first time I ran it it seemed to be okay, the second time I got `Warning: Rate limit exceeded` I think you're maxing out your API request limit, if you're seeing a similar message.

Comment: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limiting.html

Comment: You can also try adding `retryonratelimit = TRUE` to your call, but you'll probably still need to wait for the rate limiting window to reset.